# What does the following message mean in SAS?

Tags: sas

I received the following message in SAS:

> Measures of association between the observed and predicted values were not calculated
>         because the mean scored predicted probabilities are indistinguishable when they are
>         classified into intervals of length 0.008.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your predicted probabilities are all falling into the same bin width, so your model is not a good fit to your data. [See here.](http://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind0507b&L=sas-l&D=0&P=35794)